# Ansible vars file conditional dictionary item

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a requirement to use the same vars file for two different workflows, and only one dictionary key-value item differs according to the type of workflow.

```
my_vars:
  my_dict:
    key1: value1
    fookey2: foovalue2 if workflow == 'foo' else key2: value2
```

so it would be for workflow foo:

```
my_vars:
  my_dict:
    key1: value1
    fookey2: foovalue2
```

and for another workflow:

```
my_vars:
  my_dict:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
```

How can I conditionally define my_vars.my_dict?
So far I managed to do this:

```
my_vars:
  my_dict: "{{ my_dict | default({}) | combine({'key1': 'value1', 'key2' : value2|d(omit), 'fookey2' : foovalue2|d(omit) }) }}"
```

in hope that the key-value with undefined value (which depends on workflow) would be skipped, but got

```
"my_dict": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "fookey2": ""
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there with your pseudo code above. You just have to combine a base fixed element (i.e. `{'key1': 'value1'}`) with a variable element depending on the situation (i.e. either `{'fookey2': 'foovalue2'}` or `{'key2': 'value2'}`)

This is a solution using Jinja2 to define your var value

```yaml
my_dict: "{{ {'key1': 'value1'} | combine({'fookey2': 'foovalue2'} if workflow=='foo' else {'key2': 'value2'}) }}"
```

You can make this more legible by using intermediate vars:

```yaml
base_dict:
  key1: value1

foo_dict:
  fookey2: foovalue2

other_dict:
  key2: value2

my_dict: "{{ base_dict | combine(foo_dict if workflow=='foo' else other_dict }}"
```

In case you have many workflows to cope with, @Vladimir's answer goes beyond this simple example and will adapt smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

Declare the base and optional items, and combine them

```yaml
    my_dict_base:
      key1: value1

    my_dict_options:
      foo:
        key2: value2
      default:
        fookey2: foovalue2
 
    my_dict: "{{ my_dict_base|
                 combine(my_dict_options[workflow]|
                         d(my_dict_options.default)) }}"
```

Comment: Thank you! I went for simpler combine with condition from comments, but this is very elegant!